# Line integral + Work

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

$F=(z-y)i+(x-z)j+(2y-x)k$

Let $C$ be a curve formed by an intersection of the plane $2x-z=0$ with the cylinder of elliptical cross section $x^2+(y^2)/9=1$, assuming $y$ is parametrized along $C$ via $y=3\sin{t}$, where $t\in[-\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3}]$.

Find the line integral $\int_C{F \cdot d\vec{r}}$ over $C$ (assume corresponding parametric equation for $x$ is $x>0$)

I have parametrized it $x=\cos{t}$, $y=3\sin{t}$ and $z=2\cos{t}$, but I can't seem to work out what the parametrized curve is i.e. the line $r$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: your integral can be written as follows:

$$I = \int_C F(\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathrm d \mathbf{x},$$ where $\mathbf{x} = (x,y,z)$ and therefore $\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}$ is the (tangent) differential vector of the curve given by $C$. Thus, we can [write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field), since $\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d}t} \, \mathrm{d}t$:

$$I = \int_{t_0}^{t_F} F(\mathbf{x}(t)) \cdot \mathbf{x}'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t,$$ where $t_0 = -\pi/3$ and $t_F = \pi/3$. Substitute back your data and perform the 1D integral. I'm sure you can take it from here.

Cheers!

Comment: but what is x(t) ???

Comment: $\mathbf{x}(t)$ is your parameterization of the curve, i.e., $x(t) = \cos{t}, \ y(t) = 3 \sin{t}, \ z(t) = 2 \cos{t}$.

Comment: I know, but how can i express it as a single equation that is r = ....

Comment: Take into account that $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{x}$ is a vector, so $F(\mathbf{x}(t))$ is a vector field too, which is only dependent on $t$. When multiplied by $\mathbf{x}'(t)$ it becomes a sacalar and your integral is of the form $\int f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$. I'm not sure if this was what you were asking for.

Comment: I can solve the above integral, but i need to know what the "equation" for x(t) is i.e. r(t) =...i +...j+...k

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, $\mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{r}(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t)) = x(t) \vec{i} + y(t) \vec{j} + z(t) \vec{k}$.

Comment: ahhhhh i think i got it so r = costi +3sintj +2cost ? ...thanks alot!!!

Comment: You got it! Happy to help.

Comment: YES!! Thank YOU very much, greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe this animation can help you understand better what's going on: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Line_integral_of_vector_field.gif